# How can I set three icon vertically to SwipeMenuItem in SwipeMenuListView

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I add customize `SwipeMenuListView`.

I want to put three icons vertically in Menu when user swipe any item from list view it will display three icons.

Can any one help me for same.

Thanks in advance.

Like this Image
[image]

Comment: No I have never tried but i wan't to do

Comment: We can only help you if you post your code. If you can't be bothered to put effort into this, don't expect others to.

Comment: i achieved such functionality using view pager.

Comment: let me know if you need more details about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to swipe any item...

public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 300;
    private static final int MIN_LOCK_DISTANCE = 30; // disallow motion intercept
    private boolean motionInterceptDisallowed = false;
    private float downX, upX;
    private AudioObjectHolder holder;
    private int position;

    public SwipeDetector(AudioObjectHolder h, int pos) {
        holder = h;
        position = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            return true; // allow other events like Click to be processed
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            upX = event.getX();
            float deltaX = downX - upX;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_LOCK_DISTANCE && listView != null && !motionInterceptDisallowed) {
                listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                motionInterceptDisallowed = true;
            }

            if (deltaX > 0) {
                holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // if first swiped left and then swiped right
                holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            swipe(-(int) deltaX);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upX = event.getX();
            float deltaX = upX - downX;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                swipeRemove();
            } else {
                swipe(0);
            }

            if (listView != null) {
                listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                motionInterceptDisallowed = false;
            }

            holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            holder.deleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }

    return true;
    }

    private void swipe(int distance) {
        View animationView = holder.mainView;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) animationView.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = -distance;
        params.leftMargin = distance;
        animationView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private void swipeRemove() {
        remove(getItem(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is AudioObjectHolder and how can i use SwipeDetector in my class?

Comment: AudioObjectHolder is a class that is holding your View ...i m giving u Tutorial link check and try to understand.. http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview/